# How to center setLogo drawable programatically in toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

I have a custom toolbar that's built without a xml, all the code is just written in java. I am using the `setLogo()` method to add a `drawable` but the image's default `gravity` is to the left. How can I change its position/gravity so that it's in the middle?

I was trying to override the `setLogo()` method but I can't apply a `LayoutParams` to a `drawable`.

This is what I am talking about:

```java
   @Override
   public void setLogo(@DrawableRes int resId) {
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       float factor = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
       int margin = (int) (16 * factor);
       lp.setMargins(margin, 0, margin, 0);
       lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
       resId.setLayoutParams(lp);  // this does not work

       setLogo(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(getContext(), resId));
   }
```

What's the right way to achieve this without a xml to refer to?
Thanks!

Comment: Why not use [this](https://github.com/shua3343/Android-CenteredToolbar) library

Comment: @Sambhav.K thank you, that actually gives me an idea how to go about it